# Convert xml to json and extract data

Tags: java, android, json, xml

I have to extract some data from `json`.

After `HTTP GET` I convert my `xml` ( site provides `xml` only) to `json`.

When I try to extract data from `json` I got an error.

Some Advice ? 
Thanks in advance

`Xml --> <data> <user id = "value" name="value" surname = "value" /> </data>`

After conversion I have something like that

```
 Json --> {"data":{"user":[{"id":"value","name":"value","surname":"value"}]}}



   void convert(){
    String xml; //data from  HTTP GET                       
            JSONObject jsonObj = null;
            JSONObject data = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
            Log.d("JSON LOG","DATA: " + data.toString());
            try{

                jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(xml);


                JSONArray jArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("user");

                for (int i = 0 ; i < jArray.length(); i++){

                    JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = jsonObject.getString("id");

                    Log.d("JSON LOG","ID: " + id);
                   String name = jsonObject.getString("name");

                    Log.d("JSON LOG","NAME: " + name);
                String sname = jsonObject.getString("surname");

                    Log.d("JSON LOG","SNAME: " + sname);

          }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("JSON Exception",e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }//end void
```

I got the following error from `catch` ---> `E/JSON Exception: No value for user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line before `JSONArray jArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("user");`

```
JSONObject jObj1 = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
```

Your `user` JSONArray is inside a JSONObject `data`.

Comment: Perfect ! It Works. Thanks a lot!